# Prove that $\mathbb N \setminus \{5,6\}$ is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that the set $\mathbb N \setminus \{5,6\}$ is denumerable.

I know the definition is the set has to be equivalent to $\mathbb N$. But I am not too sure how that helps to prove this set particularly. Would it be something with subsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following function
$$
f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N \setminus \{5,6\}, 
n \mapsto
\begin{cases}
n & \text{, if } n < 5 \\
n+2 & \text{, otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
This is a bijection, witnessing that $\mathbb N \setminus \{5,6\}$ is denumerable. I'll leave the verification of its injectivity and surjectivity to you. (Both are easy to prove.)

Comment: @Sam $A$ is equivalent to $B$ (by definition) iff there is a bijection $f \colon A \to B$. So, yes, you have to prove that there is a bijection $f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N \setminus \{5,6\}$.

Comment: @Sam Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Okay thank you. So to prove surjection and injection we just pick elements in f and go from there using how we defended f?

Comment: @Sam Yes, to prove that $f$ is injective you have to prove that if $f(n) = f(m)$, then this already implies $n = m$. (Hint: It suffices to prove that $n < m$ implies $f(n) < f(m)$.) To prove that $f$ is surjective, you have to find for every $m \in \mathbb N \setminus \{5,6\}$ an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(n) = m$. (Hint: If $m < 5$, then $n = m$ does the job. If $m \ge 5$, then ...)

Comment: Okay surjective i get it's just injection that seems almost too trivial. If I set f(x) = f(y) then really only the variables change not really the conditions so x=y is true?

Comment: @Sam I don't know what you're trying to say with that, but here is a more detailed hint: If $f(n) = f(m)$ then, by the definition of $f$, either $n  = m$ or $n+2 = m+2$. What can you say about $m$ and $n$ in both cases?

Comment: It says that they have to be equal in either case

Comment: @Sam Correct. And that's all you need to conclude that $f$ is injective. Good job!

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks.

Comment: @Sam Yes, one case is $y < 5$, the other is $y \ge 7$.

Comment: @Sam Yes, if $y <  5$, then $y = f(y)$. If $y \ge 7$, then $y = f(y-2)$. Hence $f$ is in fact surjective.

Comment: @Sam It's separate. It follows from the definition of $f$.

Comment: Hmm, but how did you get f(y)=y? Aren't we looking for some f(x) to give us y

Comment: @Sam We need some $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. If $y < 5$, then letting $x = y$ we get that $f(x) = x = y$, so $f(y) = y$.

Comment: So we can just assume x=y?

Comment: @Sam We don't assume $x = y$, but for $y < 5$ $y$ is the unique member $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: When x<5, then f(x)< 5, meaning y<5  is satisfied?

Comment: @Sam Yes, when $x < 5$, then $f(x) = x < 5$.

Comment: Can I write When x<5, then f(x)=y<5. and for the other case, when x>or equal to 5, then f(x)=y>or equal to 7?

Comment: @Sam Yes, equivalence is symmetric. In fact, $f$ is invertable and $f^{-1} \colon \mathbb N \setminus \{ 5,6\} \to \mathbb N$ is a bijection.